# Ansible: Register and display results through iteration

Tags: ansible

My playbook is

```
---
- name: Running Checks on ACTIVATION VMs of ECM
  hosts: activationvms
  tasks:
   - name: Checking File System status
     shell: df -PTh
     register: filesystem_check
   - name: Display File System Statistics
     debug:
      msg: "{{ filesystem_check.stdout_lines }}"
   - name: Check the status of list of services
     shell: systemctl list-units|grep "{{ item }}"|awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
     with_items:
     - zookeeper.service
     - cassandra.service
     register: service_status
   - name: Display services status
     debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
     with_items: "{{ service_status.results }}"
```

I want to shrink the results to only the msg line.

```
ok: [10.142.6.79] => (item={u'_ansible_parsed': True, u'changed': True, u'stdout': u'cassandra.service loaded active running', u'_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout_lines': [u'cassandra.service loaded active running'], u'warnings': [], u'_ansible_item_result': True, u'start': u'2019-11-15 07:50:39.047456', u'delta': u'0:00:00.011821', u'cmd': u'systemctl list-units|grep "cassandra.service"|awk \'{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}\'', u'item': u'cassandra.service', u'rc': 0, u'invocation': {u'module_name': u'command', u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'systemctl list-units|grep "cassandra.service"|awk \'{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}\'', u'removes': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None}}, u'end': u'2019-11-15 07:50:39.059277', u'stderr': u''}) => {
    "item": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "systemctl list-units|grep \"cassandra.service\"|awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}'",
        "delta": "0:00:00.011821",
        "end": "2019-11-15 07:50:39.059277",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "systemctl list-units|grep \"cassandra.service\"|awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}'",
                "_uses_shell": true,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "warn": true
            },
            "module_name": "command"
        },
        "item": "cassandra.service",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-11-15 07:50:39.047456",
        "stderr": "",
        "stdout": "cassandra.service loaded active running",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "cassandra.service loaded active running"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    },
    "msg": "cassandra.service loaded active running"
}
ok: [10.142.6.72] => (item={u'_ansible_parsed': True, u'changed': True, u'stdout': u'cassandra.service loaded active running', u'_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout_lines': [u'cassandra.service loaded active running'], u'warnings': [], u'_ansible_item_result': True, u'start': u'2019-11-15 07:50:39.429296', u'delta': u'0:00:00.011853', u'cmd': u'systemctl list-units|grep "cassandra.service"|awk \'{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}\'', u'item': u'cassandra.service', u'rc': 0, u'invocation': {u'module_name': u'command', u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'systemctl list-units|grep "cassandra.service"|awk \'{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}\'', u'removes': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None}}, u'end': u'2019-11-15 07:50:39.441149', u'stderr': u''}) => {
    "item": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "systemctl list-units|grep \"cassandra.service\"|awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}'",
        "delta": "0:00:00.011853",
        "end": "2019-11-15 07:50:39.441149",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "systemctl list-units|grep \"cassandra.service\"|awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4}'",
                "_uses_shell": true,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "warn": true
            },
            "module_name": "command"
        },
        "item": "cassandra.service",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-11-15 07:50:39.429296",
        "stderr": "",
        "stdout": "cassandra.service loaded active running",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "cassandra.service loaded active running"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    },
    "msg": "cassandra.service loaded active running"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop control tool.  Rewrite your last play like this

```
- name: Display services status
  debug:
   msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ service_status.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

That will limit that output to just the thing that was iterated into your prior command so you can tell which part of the loop you are currently in.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?  I just ran that locally and it worked, so maybe sharing the error will help me see what the problem is.

Comment: Does this loop_control: and label "{{ item.item }}" works only on higher veersion of Ansible?? i use 2.1.1.0 . i don't get any error but the results are same.

Comment: The offending line appears to be:

     loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.item }}"
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

Comment: I think you are correct on it being a version issue.  This was tested on a 2.7 version.  I don't have any experience with 2.1, so it's tough for me to say what the differences between those two versions are.